# Mocking methods in test

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I have a class i want to test:

```
type ApiGateway struct {
    username  string
    password  string
    scsClient *scsClient.APIDocumentation
    auth      Auth
}

type Auth struct {
    token   string
    validTo int32
}

func New(host string, scheme string, username string, password string) *ApiGateway {
    var config = scsClient.TransportConfig{host, "/", []string{scheme}}
    var client = scsClient.NewHTTPClientWithConfig(strfmt.Default, &config)

    return &ApiGateway{username, password, client, Auth{}}
}

func (s *ApiGateway) isTokenValid() bool { ... }
```

This isTokenValid method is called from every other method inside the class in order to verify and/or update the API token. In tests I want to mock this method, so it always returns true for example.

How do I archieve that?

---

Edit: 
My Code:

**apiGateway.go**

```
type StubAdapter struct {
    ApeGatewayAdapter
}

type ApeGatewayAdapter interface {
    isTokenValid() bool
}

type ApiGateway struct {
    username  string
    password  string
    scsClient *scsClient.APIDocumentation
    auth      Auth
    adapter ApeGatewayAdapter
}

type Auth struct {
    token   string
    validTo int32
}

func New(host string, scheme string, username string, password string, a ApeGatewayAdapter) *ApiGateway {
    var config = scsClient.TransportConfig{host, "/", []string{scheme}}
    var client = scsClient.NewHTTPClientWithConfig(strfmt.Default, &config)

    return &ApiGateway{username, password, client, Auth{}, a}
}
```

**apiGateway_test.go**

```
type MockAdapter struct {
    ApeGatewayAdapter
}

func (m MockAdapter) isTokenValid() bool {
    return true
}

func TestApiGateway_GetDevice(t *testing.T) {
    var scsGateway = New("foo.com", "http", "testuser", "testpwd", MockAdapter{})

    fmt.Println(scsGateway.isTokenValid())
}
```

I would expect the test to call my mocked method and return *true* which it doesnt.

Comment: Could you show your attempts?

Comment: I created an interface containing that method as described here: https://dev.to/dmigwi/mocking-methods-in-go-5fg . I am missing the correct way how to instantiate and use the mocked class in tests

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I added the code to the first posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the `isTokenValid()` in your `MockAdapter` instead of your `ApeGatewayAdapter`. So, when you are trying to test it says that

> scsGateway.isTokenValid undefined (type *ApiGateway has no field or
>   method isTokenValid)

You need to change your architecture in your structs because you've created a method `New()` for the adaptaer (and it's okay) but the important thing here (and almost always in Go) is returning an interface!

`isTokenValid()` is defined for the external type (in your test case for the `MockAdapter`) so you cannot call it unless you change the definition of your types or you change the implementation of the method from `MockAdapter` to `ApeGatewayAdapter`.

I think the best solution should be removing the `StubAdapter` and working directly with the `ApiGateway` and define the method `isTokenValid()` for this types. Then your test should works removing the internal `ApeGatewayAdapter`and using only the `MockAdapter` to mock the apigateway and its method.

Your code should look like this:

**gateway.go**

```
package gateway

type ApeGatewayAdapter interface {
    isTokenValid() bool
}

type ApiGateway struct {
    username string
    password string
    auth     Auth
}

type Auth struct {
    token   string
    validTo int32
}

func (a ApiGateway) isTokenValid() bool {
    // TODO add your validations
    return true
}

func New(host string, scheme string, username string, password string) ApeGatewayAdapter {

    return ApiGateway{username, password, Auth{}}
}
```

**gateway_test**

```
package gateway

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type MockAdapter struct {
}

func (m MockAdapter) isTokenValid() bool {
    return true
}


func TestApiGateway_GetDevice(t *testing.T) {

    gateway := MockAdapter{}
    if gateway.isTokenValid() != true {
        t.Error("Not true")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested your code, but it still calls the isTokenValid() method on the ApiGateway type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes , sorry I've missed the fact that the "New" is not necessary here, you need to initialize new `MockAdapter` manually instead of calling the real `New()`. Otherwise, you can create a NewMock() here returning the mock... I've changed the test

Comment: Ah thanks. With type MockAdapter struct {
 ApeGatewayAdapter
} i would get access to the "original" methods.

Comment: There is still a problem. When I call gateway.GetDevice() (which makes a call to isTokenValid() ) from my test, it lands in the original isTokenValid() method and not in the stubbed one.

Comment: You need to mock all methods, you cannot decide one method yes and other no, because you're mocking the object, not the methods

Comment: Mmmh then this approach doesnt fit exactly. I want to test the logik of my original type but with one method mocked.

Comment: The thing you want to achieve is not possible. You cannot create one type with some methods, and then create a different method (mock) for the previous type just to test it. The way of doing this is using an interface and creating a mock of your type. I recommend you read this article talking about this issue in detail https://medium.com/agrea-technogies/mocking-dependencies-in-go-bb9739fef008

Comment: In my particullar case I need to extract all the token operations to a type, then i can mock it

Comment: At the end the testing is depending your code and your needs but if you undesrtand the idea I presented on the example before you'll be successfull always! Hope it helps you and feel free to contact me if need something else